# What is the time complexity of this for loop nested in a while loop?

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, big-o, computer-science

I am trying to optimize a function. I believe this nested for loop is quadratic, but I'm not positive. I have recreated the function below

```js
const bucket = [["e","f"],[],["j"],[],["p","q"]]
let totalLettersIWantBack = 4;

//I'm starting at the end of the bucket
function produceLetterArray(bucket, limit){
  let result = [];
  let countOfLettersAccumulated = 0;
  let i = bucket.length - 1;
    while(i > 0){
      if(bucket[i].length > 0){
        bucket[i].forEach( (letter) =>{
        if(countOfLettersAccumulated === totalLettersIWantBack){
          return;
        }
        result.push(letter);
       countOfLettersAccumulated++;
        })
      }
      i--;
    }
  return result;
}

console.log(produceLetterArray(bucket, totalLettersIWantBack));
```

Comment: Why did you make it a snippet, if we can't run it anyways?

Comment: @Vallentin sorry about that. It can now be executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a ***trick*** for such questions. For the code whose complexity you want to analyze, just write the time that it would take to execute **each statement** in the worst case assuming no other statement exists. Note the comments begining with  `#operations worst case:`

For the given code:

```
while(i > 0){ //#operations worst case: bucket.length
  if(bucket[i].length > 0){ //#operations worst case:: 1
    bucket[i].forEach( (letter) =>{  //#operations worst case: max(len(bucket[i])) for all i
    if(countOfLettersAccumulated === totalLettersIWantBack){ //#operations worst case:1
      return;
    }
    result.push(letter); //#operations worst case:1
   countOfLettersAccumulated++; //#operations worst case:1
    })
  }
  i--; ////#operations worst case:: 1
}
```

We can now multiply all the worst case times (*since they all can be achieved in the worst case, you can always set totalLettersIWantBack = 10^9*) to get the `O` complexity of the snippet:

Complexity = `O(bucket.length * 1 * max(len(bucket[i])) * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1)`

= `O(bucket.length * max(len(bucket[i]))`

If the length of each of the bucket[i] was a constant, `K`, then your complexity reduces to:
`O(K * bucket.length )` = `O(bucket.length)`

Note that the complexity of the push operation may not remain constant as the number of elements grow (ultimately, the runtime will need to allocate space for the added elements, and all the existing elements may have to be moved).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. So you're saying  the best case  is O(n)?

Comment: @colbisaurusrex, Sure. Yes, if the number of elements in each of the subarray is a constant, then the worst ase is indeed O(N), where N = number of elements in the outer array (bucket). Also, note that Big-O (or worst case time complexity) actually tells you how the time taken by the code changes with a change in input.  For example, bubble sort is O(n^2). If it takes 4 seconds for 4 elements, it will take 16 seconds with 8 elements. You can think of it as a rank given to each algorithm or a function.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not this is quadratic depends on what you consider N and how bucket is organized.   If N is the total number of letters, then the runtime is bound by either the number of bins in your bucket, if that is larger than N, or it is bound by the number of letters in the bucket, if N is larger.  In either case, the search time increases linearly with the larger bound, if one would dominate the other the time complexity is O(N).  This is effectively a linear search with "turns" in it, scrunching a linear search and spacing it out does not change the time complexity.  The existence of multiple loops in a piece of code does not alone make it non linear.  Take the linear search example again.  We search a list until we've found the largest element.

```js
//12 elements
var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
var rows = 3;
var cols = 4;

var largest = -1;

for(var i = 0; i < rows; ++i){

    for(var j = 0; j < cols; ++j){
        var checked = array[(i * cols) + j];
        if (checked > largest){
            largest = checked;
        }      
    } 
}
console.log("found largest number (eleven): " + largest.toString());
```

Despite this using two loops instead of one, the runtime complexity is still O(N) where N is the number of elements in the input.  Scrunching this down so each index is actually an array to multiple elements, or separating relevant elements by empty bins doesn't change the fact the runtime complexity is bound linearly.

Answer (score 0):

This is technically linear with n being the number of elements total in your matrix. This is because the exit condition is the length of *bucket* and for each array in *bucket* you check if *countOfLettersAccumulated* is equal to *totalLettersIWantBack*. Continually looking at values.

It gets a lot more complicated if you are looking for an answer matching the dimensions of your matrix because it looks like the dimensions of *bucket* are not fixed.

You can turn this bit of code into constant by adding an additional check outside the *bucket* foreach which if *countOfLettersAccumulated* is equal to 
*totalLettersIWantBack* then you do a break.

Answer (score 0):

I like [@axiom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/988966/axiom)'s [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43267851/2542172) of complexity analyze.

Just would like to add possible optimized solution.

**UPD** `.push` ([O(1)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.7)) is faster that `.concat` ([O(n^2)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.4))

also here is test [Array push vs. concat](https://jsperf.com/array-push-vs-concat)

```js
const bucket = [["e","f"],[],["j", 'm', 'b'],[],["p","q"]]
let totalLettersIWantBack = 4;

//I'm starting at the end of the bucket
function produceLetterArray(bucket, limit){
  let result = [];

  for(let i = bucket.length-1; i > 0 && result.length < totalLettersIWantBack; i--){
    //previous version
    //result = result.concat(bucket[i].slice(0, totalLettersIWantBack-result.length));
    
    //faster version of merging array
    Array.prototype.push.apply(result, bucket[i].slice(0, totalLettersIWantBack-result.length));
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(produceLetterArray(bucket, totalLettersIWantBack));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does concat make the time complexity O(n^2)?

Comment: Yeah man, you're right. I didn't know that =)
I've updated answer.